# Properly convert Magento's returned object to JSON

Tags: magento-1.7, object, json

I made a customer log-in to the site programmatically... I am properly returned the session values in form of an object.

Now i want this data carried over and returned from the function in JSON format.

I know magento has its own encoding and decoding functions... But this conversion does not some how take place properly.

I mean session object contains customer's email, first, last name,etc. But these are not reflected in converted json... So how do I convert this properly??

Thanks in advance

Here is my code..

```
<?php

function loginUser( $email, $password )
{
    require_once ("../../app/Mage.php");
    umask(0);
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));

    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->website_id = $websiteId;
    $customer->setStore($store);
    try {
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $session->login($email, $password);
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($session);
        var_dump($jsonData);

    }catch(Exception $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }


  } 

    $test = loginUser("test1.igex@gmail.com","testigex");
    //var_dump($test);
?>
```

Comment: I can't help, but little tip: add in your question what you're really getting as opposed to what you want to get. Makes the question more understandable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is  not good idea to `return a php object to json value`.As per as,php concept json is convert a string varible and an array of string variables to json object.

**Json does not capable to convert a php to  json object.**

If you want data then need to  `return customer data in array format.`

**just like:**

`$jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($customer->getData())`;

**getData() is give Customer data in array format.**

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/250148/57334 any help @Amit Bera♦