# HELP - How to convert Default SOAP-v2 API Magento Objects into XML Values?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap-api-v2, object

In Magento1.9 - product collection by default return values as Magento Objects using soap v2, how can i change into XML,

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
$proxy = new SoapClient('abc.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
$sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'abc', 'apiKey' => 'abc123'));
$result = $proxy->catalogProductInfo((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'productId' => '9700'));
var_dump($result->result);
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344920/how-to-change-magento2-soap-api-response-from-object-to-xml

Comment: @PYYick Thanks, i already tried that, no response.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137059/5336832)

Comment: why you need xml ? it is better to use Object Or Array Or Json Array

Comment: I need to pass this values to Android Based Application.

Comment: Is possible to change XML? or How can convert into JSON?

Comment: You can use `json_encode($object)`.

Comment: @PYYick Yes, i did that, json_encode($object) -> working. But my Third Party Need as XML. Is any possible  to get XML?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2194774/6643909

Comment: @PYYick Thanks for your link, we looking without pear.

Comment: This solution is without PEAR

Comment: @PYYick okay. i will try.